# Azure Websites - Drupal

Tags: drupal, azure-web-app-service

I have a Drupal site loaded up on Azure Websites but it timeouts and wont load, the database connection is fine as if I navigate to /install.php it says that there is already a installation.

Now I tested my configuration with a vanilla install of Drupal and it works fine, no error message comes up just a blank page.

The logs suggest the following

[08-Dec-2014 09:38:55 Australia/Brisbane] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in D:\home\site\wwwroot\includes\database\database.inc on line 2171

Answer (score 0):

Check how much php memory is allocated to your site. 300 seconds are enough for loading a drupal site.

Also, make sure, your website is not calling an external API which is taking a while to respond.

Comment: I have checked and it is memory_limit 128M

Comment: Set it to 400M using ini_set and try again

Comment: This still hasnt worked, I am thinking of comparing the phpinfo and see if there is modules not loaded that it is expecting, just doesnt seem like that kind of issue. Just get the WSOD.

Comment: Check apache/mysql logs. There must be some dependencies missing